# PowerShell Get Certificate Thumbprint with Password PFX File

Tags: powershell, passwords, x509certificate2

I'm trying to get the thumbprint of a password protected pfx file using this code:

```
function Get-CertificateThumbprint {
    # 
    # This will return a certificate thumbprint, null if the file isn't found or throw an exception.
    #

    param (
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)][string] $CertificatePath,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $false)][string] $CertificatePassword
    )

    try {
        if (!(Test-Path $CertificatePath)) {
            return $null;
        }

        if ($CertificatePassword) {
            $sSecStrPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $CertificatePassword -Force –AsPlainText
        }

        $certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
        $certificateObject.Import($CertificatePath, $sSecStrPassword);

        return $certificateObject.Thumbprint
    } catch [Exception] {
        # 
        # Catch accounts already added.
        throw $_;
    }
}
```

When I run it, I get this error:

```
Cannot find an overload for "Import" and the argument count: "2".
At C:\temp\test.ps1:36 char:9
+         $certificateObject.Import($CertificatePath, $sSecStrPassword);
+         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodCountCouldNotFindBest
```

Can someone please help me sort this out?

Thanks All. :-)

Answer (score 65):

According to [this SuperUser response](https://superuser.com/questions/849152/using-powershell-how-do-i-extract-the-thumbprint-from-an-ssl-certificate-withou), in PS 3.0 there is [Get-PfxCertificate command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.security/get-pfxcertificate) to do that:

```
 Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath Certificate.pfx
```

Comment: Example from Microsoft:
PS C:\> Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath "C:\windows\system32\Test.pfx"

Comment: Get-PfxCertificate does not have password parameter. See answer of kyorilys if you need to import certificate in non-interactive mode.

Comment: In 2023 it has password parameter: `(Get-PfxCertificate -FilePath $certFilePath -Password $certPassword).Thumbprint`. Password: `ConvertTo-SecureString 'myPassword' -AsPlainText -Force`

Answer (score 24):

You can do this

```
$certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$certificateObject.Import($CertificatePath, $sSecStrPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
return $certificateObject.Thumbprint
```

Remember to set this two variable:  $CertificatePath and $sSecStrPassword

UPDATED:

```
$certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificatePath, $sSecStrPassword)
```

Comment: On new versions you should use 
$certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2($CertificatePath, $sSecStrPassword)

Comment: I am getting "Exception calling "Import" with "3" argument(s): "The specified network password is not correct." . I am using your script.  Any idea ?

Comment: may be due to the new version, or like the description said, the password not correct, you have to set the $sSecStrPassword

Comment: Note to others trying this: Apparently the certificate path needs to be an absolute path. I used Resolve-Path to resolve a relative path and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 4):

The PowerShell error message is right.  There are no overloads that take two parameters.  Based on the parameters you are using I think you want the [overload that requires a third parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms148441(v=vs.110).aspx) - an enum - `X509KeyStorageFlags` e.g.

```
$certificateObject.Import($CertificatePath, $sSecStrPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I have used to read the thumbprint of a certificate in a file without importing the file on Windows PowerShell 5.1:

`$Thumbprint = (Get-PfxData -Password $MyPFXCertificatePwdSecureString -FilePath $CertificateFilePath).EndEntityCertificates.Thumbprint`

More information about Get-PfxData can be found here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/get-pfxdata

Answer (score 1):

FYI, looks like Get-PfxCertificate will add the ability to pass a password in powershell 6.0.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell-Docs/issues/2150

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to this answer: [Is there a command line utility to extract the certificate thumbprint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4540970/is-there-a-command-line-utility-to-extract-the-certificate-thumbprint)
I was able to work out the following one-liner that works great:

```
    $thumbprint = (certutil -split -dump .\cert.pfx | findstr /c:"Cert Hash(sha1)").Substring(17)[-1]
```

If the PFX is password protected,

```
    $thumbprint = (certutil -split -p the_secret_password_to_my_pfx -dump .\cert.pfx | findstr /c:"Cert Hash(sha1)").Substring(17)[-1]
```

Tehcnically, it's not pure powershell, as it invokes certutil.exe, but that should be on every Windows system, so it works.

Answer (score 1):

If you get path error in powershell, use below script:

```
$FilePath = "c:\a\"
$FileName = "mycert"
$FileType = ".pfx"
$certificateObject = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2
$certificateObject.Import($FilePath+$FileName+$FileType, $sSecStrPassword, [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::DefaultKeySet)
return $certificateObject.Thumbprint
```